# Ajax ScriptResource.axd error in firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I having trouble figuring out why my website keeps on giving me this error. It is a alert that Firefox gives me.

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

> Script: http://localhost:36698/www/ScriptResource.axd?d=ieR0oijRfmciDlnEsaawUzGJ5_1XIzUjWDCF4hnUPwJcxzUeg4BneJQ3UbckpofrO1zfhHekdfqLVV8R-aKaBVi8c-mTfWbv2_0DH5Dgx1j_3X_9U4IG0ZW5H3DO7ckZD_UtZQ2&t=ffffffffda74082d:2

Then I have the options of Continue, Debug script or Stop script.

I have `AjaxControlToolkit.7.1213\lib\45\AjaxControlToolkit.dll` installed and also included `Bootstrap v3.3.2`.

Everything is running fine in IE, Chrome and Safari but for some reason Firefox gives met the above error.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: you can't post a link addressed `localhost` to the internet. it only works on your computer.

Comment: @Dleh This is still a project in progress that is why it is in localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.
I had 2 different versions of Ajax Control Toolkit installed in my project.